# chrome error doesn't resolve source map if promise is rejected and catched

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, es6-promise

I can not get chrome to resolve my sourcemap when my promise is rejected.
In my code, I print a value then make my promise fail on purpose:

```
...
window.console.log(this);
return this._foo.bar;
...
```

[image]

- window.console.log(this) resolves properly to models.stack.js:325.
- the error doesn't resolve to models.stack.js but to the bundled code (geometries_slice.js).

Promise call:

```
Promise
.all(loadSequence)
.then(function() {
  // this part of the code will call
  //
  // ...
  // window.console.log(this);
  // return this._foo.bar
  // ...
  //
  // at some point in models.stack.js

  let series = seriesContainer[0].mergeSeries(seriesContainer)[0];
})
.catch(function(error) {
  window.console.log('oops... something went wrong...');
  window.console.log(error);
 });
```

If the error is not caught:

```
Promise
 .all(loadSequence)
 .then(function() {

   let series = seriesContainer[0].mergeSeries(seriesContainer)[0];
 })
```

Then the error is properly mapped.

[image]

Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: Can you include the promise part in your code, please?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Have you tried reporting it?

Comment: @Bergi please see edits - I didn't report it yet as I just noticed it and want to make sure it is actually a bug.

Comment: Actually maybe it is the expected behavior but would be good to map it back to original source.